# Why is imagemagick sometimes generating multiple images?

Tags: php, imagemagick-convert

My company's web server uses the command below to upload images to `$argAsset->path`. The image file name is a random number followed by '.' followed by another random number.

```
exec('/usr/bin/convert ' . $argAsset->path . ' ' . $argAsset->path . '.png');
```

I'm currently testing image upload with the exact same image each time. Sometimes this command generates a single image, and sometimes it generates multiple images. How does one make sure that ImageMagick only generates a single image for this command?

Comment: Are there spaces in the paths?

Comment: maybe you have gifs/pdfs there, and every frame(gif) or page(pdf) goes into different file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute ImageMagick to convert only the first page of the multipage PDF to JPEG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614801/how-to-execute-imagemagick-to-convert-only-the-first-page-of-the-multipage-pdf-t)

Comment: I think you need to confirm the type of image you are converting and the Imagemagick version may be useful. One thing I would suggest is use " around your file path. Also a simple test of a static filename in your code and from the same folder as the code may give some insight.