# Creating a thumbnail from pdf using c# - orientation is important

Tags: c#, pdf, thumbnails

I have been trying to create an image from PDF using c#, I have this working perfectly using the code from the example below

http://homeofcox-cs.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/c-convert-pdf-to-image-format.html

however, if the pdf is landscape then the thumbnail is not made correctly (it still thinks it's portrait and even the height/width properties are showing this as portrait).

My question is, is it possible to create a portrait or landscape thumbnail from a PDF based on its orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has also been discussed in [**'Thumbnail generation with Ghostscript rotates my device size definition for landscape pdf pages'**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326318/thumbnail-generation-with-ghostscript-rotates-my-device-size-definition-for-land).

Have a look there -- each one of the 3 answers provides hints about how you could resolve that problem. (Hint: it's a limitation of Ghostscript which you need to circumvent...)