# ghostscript pdf to thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ghostscript

I searched for this very much but didn't got the solution
I want to create a thumbnail from pdf using ghostscript of pixels 185X185. I tried using options-

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=png16m -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r35X36 -dPDFFitPage=true -dDEVICEWIDTH=185 -dDEVICEHEIGHT=185 -sOutputFile= output.%d.png input.pdf
```

I have reffered to the another question on stackover flow

[Thumbnail generation with Ghostscript rotates my device size definition for landscape pdf pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326318/thumbnail-generation-with-ghostscript-rotates-my-device-size-definition-for-land)

But image is not being created of the size i want.
How could i do this.??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add -dFIXEDMEDIA to prevent the PDF file changing the media size. I believe you can omit the -r as well, since the resolution doesn't really make any sense when you specify the media size in pixels.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes but when i remove -r some images get tilted. And if i remove -r all images are creating thumbnail of size 185X185, but some thumbnails are getting tilted

Comment: is there any option to not tilt any thumbnail

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'tilted'. If you mean the images are rotated then the answer is probably no, but its not possible to tell without seeing the file. I suspect its a feature of the PDFFitPage control, though the presence of -r should make no difference either way. The point is that there is only so much one can usefully say without seeing an example file.

Comment: Yes i think same. as some PDf's front page has less height than its width so it is considering bigger dimension as a height and small dimension as a height when using `PDFFitPage`.