# How can I get the x, y dimensions of a PDF Image

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, cmd, visual-foxpro

[image: A PDF opened in a VFP with an ActiveX control]

As you can see in the image above, the dimensions are embedded somewhere, but I know not where.  Is there a utility which I could call through shell to determine the dimensions of the PDF?

Any help is appreciated.

I used Visual FoxPro above with a browser ActiveX in a form to display PDFs HTMLs etc..., I can use any shellScript or EXEs, dlls etc, if anyone knows how to do this....
Is Javascript able to look into a browser like FireFox which has a PDF displayed, to get the dimensions???

DKean

Comment: you can use Ghostscript to do that take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943281/using-ghostscript-to-get-page-size)

Comment: Seems very interesting  user1283633 Thank you for the suggestion.  You hit the spot!